# How many maximum search definition we can make in vespa.ai?

Tags: vespa

I need to know what is the limit of the search definition in Vespa, and is there any size limit or the number of records limit in one search definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hard limits. The most search definitions/schemas I've seen are a few hundreds, and the most fields a couple of thousand.

If you need more than that it sounds like a use case where should use Map fields instead.